# Custom ordered list with paragraphs CSS

Tags: html, css, paragraph

I'm trying to get a customized ordered list to work with paragraphs and other containers but I can't get the lists to behave the same as the default.

Specifically, I would like to have a customized list and paragraphed content that appears on the same line as the enumeration. Also, I'm looking for a solution that changes the list and not the paragraph. The paragraph is just an example of some generated content that I do not wish to alter.

```css
.custom {
  list-style-type: none;
  counter-reset: elementcounter;
}

.custom li:before {
  content: counter(elementcounter) ". ";
  counter-increment: elementcounter;
}

.solution {
  list-style-type: none;
  counter-reset: elementcounter;
}

.solution li>p {
  display:        inline-block;
}

.solution li:before {
  content: counter(elementcounter) ". ";
  counter-increment: elementcounter;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li><p>Places nicely on the same line.</p></li>
  <li><p>Places nicely on the same line.</p> <p>Places nicely on the same line.</p></li>
</ol>

<!-- Original problem
<ol class="custom">
  <li><p>Places poorly on the second line.</p></li>
  <li><p>Places poorly on the second line.</p> <p>Places nicely on the second line.</p></li>
</ol>
-->

<ol class="solution">
  <li><p>Places poorly on the second line.</p></li>
  <li><p>Places poorly on the second line.</p> <p>Places poorly on the same line.</p></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: `display:inline-block` to `p` ?

Comment: I've tried but if you have a working solution, please provide a code snipit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [@Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif) mentioned, you could add `inline-block` to the `p` - like this:

```
.custom li > p {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 2px; /* you can also adjust your margins/padding if you wish */
}
```

**UPDATE**

Based on the comments (and updated question) if you have multiple paragraphs on the same `<li>` then you can add different styles for the first `p` in the list and the rest of the `p`s on the list.  Something along the lines of:

```css
.custom li > p {
  margin: 2px;
}

.custom li > p + p {
  display: block; 
  margin: 0 1.1em;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.custom li > p:first-of-type {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

<del>See demo code below..</del>

**Updated demo code based on comments**

```css
.custom {
  list-style-type: none;
  counter-reset: elementcounter;
}

.custom li:before {
  content: counter(elementcounter) ". ";
  counter-increment: elementcounter;
}

.custom li > p {
  margin: 2px;
}

.custom li > p + p {
  display: block; 
  margin: 0 1.1em;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.custom li > p:first-of-type {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>
    <p>Places nicely on the same line.</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Places nicely on the same line.</p>
  </li>
</ol>

<ol class="custom">
  <li><p>Places poorly on the second line.</p></li>
  <li><p>Places poorly on the second line.</p> <p>Places poorly on the same line.</p></li>
  <li><p>Places poorly on the second line.</p></li>
  <li><p>Places poorly on the second line.</p> <p>Places poorly on the same line.</p></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: That is awesome! Thanks guys, but it still doesn't perform the same as the original list. I've altered the second item to contain two paragraphs. The non-custom list gets the expected behaviour but the solution does not (there is no break line in between paragraphs).

Comment: @fcimeson I am not sure if I understood your comment but **I updated my answer based on what I understood** - you will need to adjust the `margin` values based on the `font-family` and `font-size` you are using (and other styles applied to your page such as `padding`  etc... The above is just a starting point

Comment: Looking better! It's a bit of a pain that the margins have to be adjusted tho. Do you know what the default ordered list is setup as (for css)?

Comment: oh man, there are some defaults (https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp) but a lot of default *values* are also inherited from parent so I do not know an easy answer to that question.